# Find and classify the singularities of $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let
>   $$f(z) = \frac{e^z\sin(3z)}{(z^2-2)z^2}$$
>   Find and classify the singularities of $f(z)$.

So far I have that there are singularities at $0$, $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$. Are these correct? Are there any more I am missing?

Also how do I classify them? Are $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$ simple poles?

Is $0$ a pole of order $2$? I am confused by the $e^z$ and the $\sin(3z)$.

Thanks

Comment: Are you only considering the domain to be the complex plane, or are you using the extended complex plane? $e^z$ and $\sin z$ both have essential singularities at $\infty$.

Comment: i don't know what an extended complex plane is so i assume just the complex plane

Comment: OK. Then you are fine. $\pm\sqrt2$ are simple poles.

Comment: Is 0 a pole of order 2?

Comment: That's correct. :)

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. Because $\sin3z$ has a simple zero at $z=0$, the function only has a simple pole at $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. the pole's are $\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2}$ and $0$. All of them are simple pole's. Because: $$f(z)=\frac{\frac{\mathbb e^z\sin(3z)}{(z-\sqrt2)z^2}}{z+\sqrt2}=\frac{\frac{\mathbb e^z\sin(3z)}{(z+\sqrt2)z^2}}{z-\sqrt2}=\frac{\mathbb e^z\frac{\sin(3z)}{z(z^2-2)}}{z}$$
$0$ is simple, because the function $\frac{\sin(3z)}{z}$ is analytic. Since: $$\sin(3z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(3z)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ From here: $$\frac{\sin(3z)}{z}=3-\frac{3^3z^2}{3!}+\frac{3^5z^4}{5!}-...+\frac{(-1)^n3^{2n+1}z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}+...$$ Which means: $\frac{\sin(3z)}{z}$ is analytic at $0$.

Comment: Why $0$ is simple warrants an explanation.

Comment: @GitGud: Did the explanation enough? If not, I can explain more.

Comment: I think it's fine now.

Comment: How does the expansion show that the function is analytic at zero? Is it something to do with the powers of z all being even?

Comment: @Koala No. It is analytic because of this theorem: **Theorem:** The power series $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ defines a analytic function in its disc of convergence. The derivative of $f$ is also a
power series obtained by differentiating term by term the series for $f$,
that is, $f'(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nz^{n-1}$. Moreover, $f'$ has the same radius of convergence as $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like $\pm \sqrt{2}$ are your two obvious simple poles (Multiplicity 1). However, to analyze the $z^2$ term, we should expand $e^z$ and $\sin(3z)$ into their Taylor series representations to see what happens.

$$e^z = 1 + z + \frac{z^2}{2} + \frac{z^3}{6} + ...$$
$$\sin(3z) = 3z + \frac{27z^3}{6} + \frac{243z^5}{120} + ...$$

By doing this we will notice something: There will actually not be any way for a $z^2$ term to appear in the denominator after multiplying this out and distributing $1/z^2$. As can be seen, the minimum degree of the numerator is going to be $1$ after multiplying our two Taylor expansions, and then after that, it blows up from there. Thus, the maximum possible degree of $z$ in the numerator is going to be $1$. Therefore, instead of a degree $2$ pole, you actually have a simple pole in disguise at $z=0$.

So, you have $3$ simple poles, $\pm \sqrt{2}$ and $0$.