# Finding and classifying the singularities of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

**Question** 
Find and classify the singularities of $f(z)=\dfrac{e^{-z}\sin(2(z-1)^2)}{(z^2-4)(z-1)^2}$.

**My Answer**

The denominator has zero's at $-2,1$ and $2$. I found both $-2$ and $2$ to be simple poles as the denominator has a zero of order $1$ at $z=2,-2$ and the numerator does not vanish at either point.

I am unsure how to classify $z=1$. I looked online and found that if the function $g(z)=\frac{\sin(2(z-1)^2)}{z-1}$ is analytic then $z=1$ is a simple pole. I found the Taylor expansion of this function to be, $\frac{\sin(2(z-1)^2)}{z-1}=2(z-1)-\frac{2^3(z-1)^7}{3!}+\frac{2^5(z-1)^9}{5!}-\cdots$ but I dont understand why this means that $g(z)$ is analytic or why this implies that $z=1$ is a simple pole. Am I going about this in the right way or is there a simpler method to classify this singularity?

**How I calculated the Taylor expansion**

$$\sin(z)= z - \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^5}{5!} - \cdots$$

$$\sin((z-1)^2) = (z-1)^2 - \frac{(z-1)^6}{3!} + \frac{(z-1)^{10}}{5!} - \cdots$$

$$\sin(2(z-1)^2) = 2(z-1)^2 - \frac{2^3(z-1)^8}{3!} + \frac{2^5(z-1)^{10}}{5!} - \cdots$$

$$\frac{\sin(2(z-1)^2)}{z-1} = 2(z-1) - \frac{2^3(z-1)^7}{3!} + \frac{2^5(z-1)^9}{5!} - \cdots$$

Comment: There are mistakes in your $g(z)$.  First, shouldn't the denominator be squared to match your question?  Second, your series isn't right.

Comment: Your Taylor expansion shows in fact that z=1 is not a singularity: given your Taylor expansion what is the value of f(1)?

Comment: Does $f(1)=0$? I tried doing what the first answer to this question did: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294533/find-and-classify-the-singularities-of-fz . Would I need to divide by $(z-1)^2$ then?

Comment: I have added in how I tried to calculate the Taylor expansion. Could you explain what I did wrong. I was confused on how to deal with the $(z-1)^2$ part.

Comment: @Koala The second step in your Taylor expansion computation is wrong. You should replace $z^3$ with $((z-1)^2)^3$ which is $(z - 1)^6$, not $(z - 1)^5$. You have similar errors in other places

Comment: Thanks, I will edit my answer

Comment: Isn't there a singularity at $\Im{z}=0$ and $\Re{z}=-\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the part of the function which is analytic at $z=1$, namely $\frac{e^{-z}}{z^2-4}$, and consider the remaining part, $g(z)=\frac{sin(2(z-1)^2)}{(z-1)^2}$. Define $h(z)=sin(2(z-1)^2)$. Notice that $h(1)=0, h'(1)=0$ but $h''(1) \neq 0$. Thus $h(z)$ has a zero of order 2 at z=1. Since the denominator of this function also has a zero of order 2 at z=1, the singularity is removable and its residue is zero.